# is it possible to see how many/who has signed up for open beta?

Tags: android, developer-console

I have set up my app and prepared open beta using the Android Developer Console, but now I want to know how many have signed up for the beta. Is it possible to:

- See how many signed up for open beta?
- See who (by email) signed up for open beta?

I tried a google search, but all that appeared was information about alpha/beta testing and how to use it. There was nothing on seeing who/how many signed up for it.

Is this possible?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Comment: I think this is _probably_ on-topic - "how to use the console itself" doesn't really fit the sort of policy/customer support questions that that post is talking about.  It's just like a question about how to use any other software development webapp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can see how many users have enrolled to be beta testers. You need to go under the "Beta testing" tab in the "APK" section. See screenshot:

[image]

You can't see the user email though.

Comment: If there are noone who has signed up, will nothing appear?

Comment: Not sure exactly but it would make sense. Keep also in mind that the developer console doesn't show realtime data so it might need a day or two to update that counter.

Comment: In my experience, it is two days. I posted the first link one month ago, so noone has signed up I guess. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Where do we go now that everything in console changed after last Google I/O?

Comment: so we cant see who all have enrolled for the beta testing for our app?

Comment: @NukeouT well, it has changed again. For future visitors though: Change back to the classic Play Console, then under Release Management -> App Releases -> Manage Beta you can see how many devices run your beta versions. Sadly, I didn't find a way to find this number in the new Play Console

Answer (score 12):

**Update (August 2022)**
There's an additional option if you go to Statistics. Configure the report by "Users -> Installed audience -> All Users" *OR* "Device -> Install base -> All devices" (note, you can click "Select another metric" to view both). Then click "View By" and select "App version". Use the filter chips to display your version. Scroll to the bottom to see the data table, the latest date row can show you exactly how many users/devices have your app with that version.

[image]

**Update (December 2021)**: As commented by @alexislg, the testers count isn't there any longer. If you open "Open Testing" (or another track), and if you have testers, the count will show up in the summary toward the top.

**Original answer (2020)**: With the update to the redesign (as of Oct. 12 2020), just go to the **Releases** section and click **Releases overview**. You'll see how many testers are currently enrolled for each track.

[image]

Comment: Does this actually work? I am seeing 0 testers on multiple apps, as in your screenshot, but I know that I have at least a few on each of them.

Comment: It should. In my case I didn't have any testers at the time, so 0 was accurate. I'm willing to bet that it's representative of how many people are actually using your beta build as opposed to how many people are enrolled. Once you promote your testing build to production, that number will drop to 0 again (or say "Inactive") as it's superseded by production.

Comment: Ok, it's probably because the apps have already been promoted to production. Would still be useful to know how many users are signed up for beta testing.

Comment: Invisible in December 2021.

Comment: Yeah, this is not visible, it only says "Active - Countries / regions synced with production"

Answer (score 3):

With recent changes, you can check number of beta testers using Release Management option.

> Select your app -> Release -> Testing -> Open testing

[image]

Comment: As of March 6, 2021 it's: `Select your app -> Release Overview` number of testers will be under a header titled **Summary of all tracks**

Answer (score 2):

*Statistics > Devices > Install base*
*View by: App version*

The button "+ App version" gives you a select that has the exact number of installs for every version.
This way you can determine how many people run your latest beta build.